# Are Relational DBMS actually difficult to scale?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, consistency, non-relational-database

I know there are similar questions on SO but some are a decade old and others don't have helpful answers.

I am a newbie in the system designing world. I have some experience with relational DBMS where I created some small scale projects.

Every post on 'Relational vs Non-Relational DBMS' points out that because of ACID transactions, Ref integrity constraints and consistency, Relational DBMS are difficult to scale. But on the other hand giants like Amazon and financial services continue to use relational DBMS and they don't seem to have any problems with scalability.

I just want to theoretically understand if relational DBMS are actually difficult to scale? If it is, how are these companies using it with terabytes of data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is in Third Normal Form, and appropriate indexes are applied, there should be no problem. This requires knowing what data is to be stored and how it needs to be accessed.

At some scale (e.g. I had a system which added up to 18 million rows per day to 1 table) you may want to have a process in place to transfer new data to an Analysis database (OLAP - e.g. SQL Server Analysis Database, MSAS). An OLAP is relatively easy to design, but the process to keep it up-to-date on even a daily basis can be difficult to design and manage without some experience. Queries to an OLAP database are optimised for reporting; I don't believe that any query for the system I mentioned ever took more than an average of 3 seconds to complete.

Comment: But let's say I don't normalize the data and also use indexing, still if I would perform ACID transactions on a sharded data, after a certain point the performance will suffer right?

Comment: Normalizing and ACID have nothing to do with each other. If you don't normalize the underlying data then queries will underperform from the start and get worse. However if a set of un-normalized tables are derived from normalized data then reporting performance can be improved - OLAP databases are basically just that.

Comment: Yes Normalizing and ACID have nothing to do with each other. What I meant was, even if I take steps to improve the performance by NOT normalizing the data (which means no joins but yes the write operations will be slow) and applying indexing, still if I shard the data the relational databases won't scale beyond a certain point because of ACID transactions. Am I right?

Comment: Never heard of ACID causing performance problems in normalised db's. I did come across it in a case where I convinced myself that denormalisation was necessary; I was wrong.

Comment: Doesn't matter if I normalize or don't, Sharding the data anyway will impact the performance right, because of ACID transactions? Also if the related tables are stored on separate machines (probably because of storage space limits), the joins will get quite expensive. Which brings me back to the same point, how are these big companies able to scale their relational databases without losing performance.

Comment: Sharding *may* impact performance, depending on its implementation and your network physical design. ACID transactions will not affect that for good or bad. BigCos get good performance by wringing every drop out of every option (good 3NF, well sized machines, those machines in a 'close' network with the fastest network between them, and local fast SAN). The hardest part is the physical machine and network design. It sounds like you don't wat to do 3NF; your choice, your problem. My advice is clear.

Comment: LOL. Sorry didn't wanna piss you off. But I get it, you advised to keep the data in 3NF. And that's a good advice. It's just that according to every SO post on scalability, the big enemy of scalability seems to be the ACID transactions on sharded data because acquiring locks, changing data and releasing locks on tables stored on separate machines probably will take more time than if the same was done on a single machine. That's why I was trying to push that point. But I think like you said machines in a closed network might be the reason. Point Taken! :)

Comment: Search on the phrases 'eventual consistency' and 'idempotent messages'. Implementing a system that uses these concepts is a complicated thing to do, but if you have e.g. an Amazon-scale system to design then you'll need these concepts. Sharding can be done two ways: some products here and some there, or products here here and orders there; or the two options can be mixed. In these systems a distributed transaction is a very fragile thing, and the option I like is: don't even bother. Implement eventual consistency via idempotent messages.